# Putnam 2000 A1 Series square problem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, contest-math

> Let $A$ be a positive real number. What are the possible values of $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x_j^2, $ given that $x_0, x_1, \cdots$ are positive numbers for which $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x_j = A$?

I got the first part to be:

$$0 < x_j < A \tag1$$

$$0 < \frac{x_j}{A} < 1 \implies 0 < \left(\frac{x_j}{A}  \right)^2 < \frac{x_j}{A} \tag2$$

Which gives:

$$0 < \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{x_j}{A}  \right)^2 < \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x_j}{A} = 1$$

Multiplying by $A^2$ gives:

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{x_j}{A}  \right)^2  < A^2$$

(1) holds because if $x_j \ge A$ then $x_{j+1} =0$ or $x_{j+1} < 0$.

The next part for the **lower bound is harder.**

I showed that:$$0 < \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{x_j}{A}  \right)^2 < \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x_j}{A} = 1$$

Which actually really means,

$$0 < \sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}} x_j^2 < A^2$$

Is this enough, or is there a fault.

But AOPS showed the second part as:

> As for the second part, let $0 < r < 1$ and let $x_j = A(1 - r)r^j.$ Then  $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x_j  =  A$ as a geometric series and
>   $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x_j^2 =  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} A^2(1 - r)^2r^{2j}  =  \frac{A^2(1 - r)^2}{1 - r^2}   =  \frac{A^2(1 - r)}{1 + r}  $
>   Clearly, we can make  $\frac{1 - r}{1 + r}$ take on any value in $(0, 1)$ by choosing an appropriate value of $r$ in $(0, 1).$ (In particular, $x  =  \frac{1 - r}{1 + r}$ if $r =  \frac{1 - x}{1 + x}  .$ )

*Was that necessary?*

Comment: Yes, it was necessary. Your reasoning shows that the sum has to be $> 0$, but it doesn't show that the sum can be as small as we like as long as it's positive.

Comment: It's more than that even, you not only need to show that you can get arbitrarily close to $0$, you also need to show you can hit every value between $0$ and $A^2$.